# Jquery Set Active Tab to Anchor Link

Tags: php, jquery, html, url, anchor

I have the following jQuery code:

```
 $(function() {
  // constants
  var SHOW_CLASS = 'show',
      HIDE_CLASS = 'hide',
      ACTIVE_CLASS = 'active';

  // $( ".tabs" ).tabs( { disabled: [1, 2] } ); 

  $( '.tabs' ).on( 'click', 'li a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $tab = $( this ),
        href = $tab.attr( 'href' );

    $( '.active' ).removeClass( ACTIVE_CLASS );
    $tab.addClass( ACTIVE_CLASS );

    $( '.show' )
       .removeClass( SHOW_CLASS )
       .addClass( HIDE_CLASS )
       .hide();

     $(href)
       .removeClass( HIDE_CLASS )
       .addClass( SHOW_CLASS )
       .hide()
       .fadeIn( 550 );
  });       
});
```

When I submit a Form below a Tab e.g.

```
<form action="#coreData" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

The URL will be like `mypage.com/home.php#coreData`.

How do I achieve the following?-

Whenever an Anchor Link (see above) is present the Active Tab should be the referenced Tab. In this case the active tab should be the tab with the #coreData a href.

HTML CODE Tabs Creation

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li>
        <a href="#uploadPicture" class="active">Picutre</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#coreData">Core Data</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#aboutMe">About You</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#keywords">(Yaa) Job</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#location">Location</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#cv">Your CV</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#attachments">Attachments</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

On page load, look at the value of `document.location.hash`, then set the active state on the corresponding tab.

To make it easier, you probably want to use IDs or class names

```
<a class="coreData" href="#coreData">
```

then..

```
$("."+yourhashvalue).addClass('active');
```